# Can WMI query a class property and filter using another class property?

Tags: wmi, wmic, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

I am a WMI noob. I'm using BGInfo and have a device with 2 NICs. I'm trying to query the IP address of one of the NICs. I want to submit a query based on the name of the NIC.

However, I'm running into an issue where the IP address is stored in Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration and the NIC name is stored in Win32_NetworkAdapter.

I want to build a WMI query like the following:

```
SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Win32_NetworkAdapter.Name="My NIC Name".
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *basic* understanding, run (from an open `cmd` window) the following command lines

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter get DeviceID, Index, InterfaceIndex, Name, NetConnectionId
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration get Index, InterfaceIndex, IPAddress
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting
```

and read the following documentation:

- [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter) - represents a network adapter of a computer running a Windows operating system (deprecated?),
- [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) - represents the attributes and behaviors of a network adapter,
- [Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadaptersetting) - association `WMI` class relates a network adapter and its configuration settings.

Then you can understand how works the following code snippet (if you use a real value for `_adapterName` instead of the *My NIC Name* placeholder):

```
set "_adapterName=My NIC Name"
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "Name='%_adapterName%'" ASSOC:value /RESULTCLASS:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

Finally, you can restrict above output to the `IPAddress=…` line as follows:

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "Name='%_adapterName%'" ASSOC:value /RESULTCLASS:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | findstr "^IPAddress"
```